# SSIS and The Excel Files Saga

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a Excel File (xls) that has a column called Money. In the Money column all the columns are formatted as number, except for some that have that marker saying formatted as text against them. I convert the Excel file to CSV using a c# script that uses IMEX=1 in the connection string to open it. The fields that are marked with stored as text do not come through to the csv file. The file is large, about 20MB. So this means 100 values like 33344 etc do not come thro the csv file.

I tried to put a delay in where I open the Excel File. This worked on my PC but not the Development machine.

Have any idea how to get round this without manually intervention, like format all columns with mixed data types as number etc ? I am looking for an automated solution that works every time . This is on SSIS 2008.

```
static void ConvertExcelToCsv(string excelFilePath, string csvOutputFile, int worksheetNumber = 1) {
   if (!File.Exists(excelFilePath)) throw new FileNotFoundException(excelFilePath);
   if (File.Exists(csvOutputFile)) throw new ArgumentException("File exists: " + csvOutputFile);

   // connection string
   var cnnStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO\"", excelFilePath);
   var cnn = new OleDbConnection(cnnStr);

   // get schema, then data
   var dt = new DataTable();
   try {
      cnn.Open();
      var schemaTable = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
      if (schemaTable.Rows.Count < worksheetNumber) throw new ArgumentException("The worksheet number provided cannot be found in the spreadsheet");
      string worksheet = schemaTable.Rows[worksheetNumber - 1]["table_name"].ToString().Replace("'", "");
      string sql = String.Format("select * from [{0}]", worksheet);
      var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
      da.Fill(dt);
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      // ???
      throw e;
   }
   finally {
      // free resources
      cnn.Close();
   }

   // write out CSV data
   using (var wtr = new StreamWriter(csvOutputFile)) {
      foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
         bool firstLine = true;
         foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) {
            if (!firstLine) { wtr.Write(","); } else { firstLine = false; }
            var data = row[col.ColumnName].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"");
            wtr.Write(String.Format("\"{0}\"", data));
         }
         wtr.WriteLine();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with SSIS?    Is the C# function above in a script task?

Comment: They don't want to introduce a manual step in process and can rely on the people to do this every week unfortunatley. If the solution is that you need to identify the columns with mixed data types and format them as text or number then I will have to work out in c# how to do this.

Comment: This is a script task in SSIS

Comment: Does the location of the 'text' rows have any impact? So, if you move all of the rows with 'money as text' to the top of the file, does the behaviour change?
If so, look at the TypeGuessRows setting in the registry. I can provide more details of required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to specify a format for the incoming files which said no columns with mixed data types. Solution was from business side and not technology.